# How to change font in TinyMCE?

Tags: next.js, tinymce

We can change the font using, for example the `content_styles` property:

```js
content_style: `
  body {
    font-family: whateva;
  }
`,
```

The problem with this approach is that the editor is loaded into an iframe and thus, fonts already loaded into the page, are not available.

This is how I load my font into the page:

```js
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'

const inter = Inter({
  subsets: ['latin'],
  display: 'swap',
})
 
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" className={inter.className}>
      <body>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

How can I use my Inter font as the default font in my TinyMCE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime, I found the solution myself:

With the new [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app) we can deterministically determine the URI of the `css`-file and use it like that

```
content_style: `
  @import url("/_next/static/css/app/layout.css");
  body {
    font-family: ${inter.style.fontFamily};
  }
`,
```

(This is a simplified example.)